# Adding CSS via JQuery not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I am trying to set a background-image utilizing this function:

```
$('#frame').css('background-image','url(floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png)');
```

Where floor is a variable containing a number from 1-7.

It works on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. But on IE it is not setting the background image. Does `.css();` work on IE?

EDIT: This is the whole script:

```
$('#secondary-nav li').click(function(){
    var floor = $(this).attr('id').replace('f','');


    $('#frame').fadeOut(200);
    $('#secondary-nav li').removeClass('current');

    var currentFloor = '';

    setTimeout(function() {
        currentFloor = '#f' + floor;

        $(currentFloor).addClass('current');

        $('.units').css('display','none');

        var image = 'url(floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png)';


        $('#frame').css('background-image', image);


        $('#frame').fadeIn(200);
        $('#floor'+floor).fadeIn(200);
    }, 500);
});

// highlight on mouseover
 $(".units div a").hover(
        function(){
            $('img',this).stop().animate({'opacity':0},200);
         }, 
        function(){
            $('img',this).stop().animate({'opacity':1},200);
         }
 ); 




// display floorplan
$('.units div').each(function(i){
    var floor = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('floor','');

    var unit = floor + $(this).attr('class').replace('u','');

    var details = $('a',this).attr('title');

    var group = $('a',this).attr('class').replace('i','');


    $(this).click(function(){
        $('#details .info h1').html('Unit '+unit);
        $('#details .info h2').html(details);
        $('#details .info a').attr('href','floorplans/downloads/'+group+'.pdf');
        $('#details .floorplate img').attr('src','floorplans/img/floorplans/floorplates/Unit-'+unit+'.png');
        $('#details .floorplan img').attr('src','floorplans/img/floorplans/'+group+'.png');
    });
    $(this).fancybox({'href':'#details'});
});
```

Comment: This is a stretch, but: What happens if you wrap the actual URL in double-quotes?

Comment: show your math for 'floor'. maybe it is a calculating problem of the IE

Comment: Yes, `.css()` works in IE. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I added double-quotes around the URL and it didn't work.

Comment: I think it is all IE. This is the link of where the image is not being set: http://www.southstarlofts.com/loft-floorplans/

Comment: Oh and floor is a string.

Comment: what do you mean *does not work*? Is the css updating. Can you see it when you inspect the field?

Comment: @Liam the css is not updating, it does not set the value for background-image

Comment: Never use `console.log` in IE.  Remove that, will work.

Comment: @user1671639,@sayra90 You can use `console.log` while in development mode, provided you remember to have the developer toolbar open when testing in IE, `console.log` only kills processing when dev bar isn't open

Comment: Removed console.log, still not setting the background-image

Comment: @AndréDion I am using jquery-1.4.2

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yup, right. when moving to production, I usually remove it.   `@sayra90` are you referrring to the correct folder?

Comment: I'm looking at your site from IE9 and I don't see the issue. What version of IE and what OS are you testing with?

Comment: IE8 and IE7. I am working on a Mac so I was using browser stack to test. The client is also saying it does not work on their IE8 and IE7.

Comment: Try adding / in starting like `/floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png"`  usually I used to do like `../floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png"`

Comment: @user1671639 added the / , didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is really unpredictable.

But following are my assumptions:

(1) Never use `console.log` when you go for production IE, console object is only exposed when the developer tools are opened for a particular tab.

so Remove your `console.log`.

(2) Are you referring to right folder path?

(3) Usually file path is prefixed with `/`.  So maybe that cause the issue.

(4) Better have something like this:

```
var imageUrl = 'floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png';   
$('#frame').css('background-image',imageUrl);
```

Hope within this your problem should exist.

Comment: I have changed that and still no dice. Maybe the problem is coming from somewhere else in the function but I doubt it. When I hover it is showing me that the #frame background-image has not been updated and that is the only part where it is being set.

Comment: @sayra90 Are you getting the right value in `floor`? ie., your `image name === floor`

Comment: yes, I even logged it to check. I mean it works on chrome, safari and firefox. the value for floor does correspond with the actual floor.

Comment: Are you sure the image is really a PNG? IE has problems with rendering the image if it is not really a PNG but for example a JPEG image where the extension is changed to PNG.

Comment: let me check. I did not program any of this, but came on board and now I am in charge of debugging it... and clearly not doing the best job

Comment: @sayra90 Let try this.  Add this line `console.log($('#frame').css('background-image'));` before and after that `.css()` code.

Comment: Ok so I added it and it shows the same in both browsers. Then maybe that is being set correctly and what is not working is the hover that shows the pink color. On IE7 when I hover the map instead of showing the pink hover it shows gray but the floorplan changes to the wrong one...

Comment: that is coming from this: 
$(".units div").hover(function(){$('img',this).stop().animate({opacity:0},200);}, 
        function(){$('img',this).stop().animate({opacity:1},200);});

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `toString()` function to your variable floor. It worked for me when I was having the exact same problem ;-)